# Appending <li> items dynamically to <ol> in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I wonder why the list items are added some times with duplicated items?

Is this code $(".product-items").append(response); correct?
The original issue is int his link in which duplicate items are added on load more products
http://womensebookstore.com/1/category.asp?cat=16

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.loadmore',function () {

  var response ="<li>This is a test list</li>";

  $(".product-items").append(response);

});
```

## HTML

```
<div class="products  products-grid" >
<ol class="product-items row">
</ol>
</div>

<li class="loadbutton"><button class="loadmore" ></li>
```

Comment: which is the expected behaviour of append method, what is the question ?

Comment: `<li class="loadbutton"><button class="loadmore" ></li>` what is this element li outside ul/ol?

Comment: Please describe **clearly** what you are expecting to see and what you are actually seeing. As it is now, I would expect to see `<li>This is a test list</li>` added to your `<ol>` **each time** you click the button

Comment: Please see the link whey it is duplicated

Comment: Please provide an example that is not an entire page. It is hard to tell what exactly is not behaving as expected in that context. Also be aware that `append` does exactly what it says. It does not care if an item exists that may be a duplicate. That is something you have to code for.

Answer (score -1):

You can only append an html element. 'response' here is string. Try this-

```js
var item = document.createElement("li");
item.innerHTML = "This is a test";
$(".product-items").append(item);
```

Comment: Please check http://womensebookstore.com/1/category.asp?cat=16 and click on load more button till end of products

Comment: OP is using jQuery. The content can be an HTML string. See http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-content-content